# Maps automatically searches for last phone number

Tags: google-maps, search

I have a Pixel 4a, using Fi for service.
Build RQ3A.210605.005 (up to date, as far as I know)

Since the last update or two, I find Maps open for no reason. It's searched for a phone number, which I've never done myself. Over time I realized that the phone number is always the most recent in my call list... incoming or outgoing.

I don't use sketchy apps, so I doubt it's malware. Any thoughts on a cause, or a fix?
Thanks!

Comment: You say "Maps".  Do you mean Google Maps, or another mapping app?

Comment: Thanks. Google Maps.